# Intermittent failure to deliver static content from tomcat

Tags: http, tomcat

I have a javascript file (and have seen this with other static content) that is sometimes not being delivered correctly by tomcat, despite a 200 response. I have tried server versions 6.0.18 and 6.0.33 with the same result. Below is an example of the result I see using wget to request the same item several times, feel free to try yourself if that helps:

--20:00:46--  http://t-pen.org/TPEN/transcription.js
           => `transcription.js.28'
Resolving t-pen.org... 165.134.241.71
Connecting to t-pen.org|165.134.241.71|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified

(See no mime type)

--20:01:06--  http://t-pen.org/TPEN/transcription.js
           => `transcription.js.29'
Resolving t-pen.org... 165.134.241.71
Connecting to t-pen.org|165.134.241.71|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 97,373 (95K) [text/javascript]

The problem in the browser is a message stating that the mime type for the javascript is incorrect. I havent messed with the mime type configuration in tomcat, and it comes through correctly most times, so I really dont know where I can look to try to solve this. Any help is much appreciated.

`curl` output for problematic GET:

```
$ curl -v http://t-pen.org/TPEN/transcription.js > /dev/null
> GET /TPEN/transcription.js HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.6 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.6 OpenSSL/1.0.0e zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.22 librtmp/2.3
> Host: t-pen.org
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Thu, 27 Oct 2011 20:43:55 GMT
< 
{ [data not shown]
100 97373    0 97373    0     0  86338      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--  112k
```

and normal one:

```
$ curl -v http://t-pen.org/TPEN/transcription.js > /dev/null
> GET /TPEN/transcription.js HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.6 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.6 OpenSSL/1.0.0e zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.22 librtmp/2.3
> Host: t-pen.org
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< ETag: W/"97373-1319761050000"
< Last-Modified: Fri, 28 Oct 2011 00:17:30 GMT
< Content-Type: text/javascript
< Content-Length: 97373
< Date: Thu, 27 Oct 2011 20:45:21 GMT
< 
{ [data not shown]
100 97373  100 97373    0     0  86196      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  112k
```

Comment: I did some experimenting with `curl` and find out that few other headers are not sent for bogus GETs. Since this is not an answer but it also didn't fit in comment I let myself modify your question, hope you don't mind and it will help.

Comment: Do you have any filter? How is your servlet-mappings look like?

Comment: I did some reading based on the chunked transfer you were seeing and I think I have it narrowed down to being unique to the http/1.1 connector. If I use AJP I dont seem to be able to get the error. ill keep testing and make that an answer if it turns out to be the case. Thanks!

Comment: palacsint I have 1 filter, though I have tried removing it. My servlet mapping is just a list of servlet names and urls that woudlnt impact the javascript, like: <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>processImage</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/processImage</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

Comment: The url in the original post will no longer work due to the work around we are using.

Answer (score 1):

Our solution to the problem is to move static content to a location served by apache and then use AJP through apache rather than direct requests to tomcat, because the AJP requests are serviced by the AJP connector rather than the HTTP/1.1 connector which is causing our troubles. This doesnt fully explain the cause of the issue, but this is how we are working around it.